# Split an array into branches merge with another array to it into tuple using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have this `array1`:

```
[
[1,2,3,4],
[4,6,2,3],
[6,5,4,2],
[8,3,9,1],
[4,4,2,2]
]
```

and `array2`:

```
[5,2,3,1,1]
```

I would like to have a list of tuples that look like that:

```
[
([1,2,3,4],5),
([4,6,2,3],2),
([6,5,4,2],3),
([8,3,9,1],1),
([4,4,2,2],1)
]
```

How can it be done with numpy only? I first thought about making a new list, and making a loop on each item in array1 and merge them together, but I'm sure it can be done more easily with numpy?

Comment: Are those arrays actually  numpy arrays or lists? If they're Python lists then stick to that, otherwise, why would you want to even use numpy to try and make something that's basically going to be useless in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have numpy arraays you can use builtin [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function like this:

```
np.array(list(zip(array1,array2)))
```

However If you have normal arrays You don't need numpy to do that:

```
>>> print(zip(array1, array2))
[([1, 2, 3, 4], 5), ([4, 6, 2, 3], 2), ([6, 5, 4, 2], 3), ([8, 3, 9, 1], 1), ([4, 4, 2, 2], 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
merged_list = [(list1[i], list2[i]) for i in range(0, len(list1))]
```